# Find empty and null values in object and update in a counter javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, object

I have the below object and I want to count the empty or `null` values in the object and update it in a property counter of that object.

E.g. I have this below object.

```
var userData = {
  firstName: "Eric",
  lastName: null,
  age: "",
  location : "San francisco",
  country: "USA",
  counter: 0
}
```

The result of iterating through this object would let us know that lastName and age is empty or null, so it should update counter: 2 indicating that 2 fields are empty.

```
obj userData = {
  firstName: "Eric",
  lastName: null,
  age: "",
  location : "San francisco",
  country: "USA",
  counter: 2
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter through the values of the object using a `Set` to store all values considered empty.

```js
const userData = {
  firstName: "Eric",
  lastName: null,
  age: "",
  location : "San francisco",
  country: "USA",
  counter: 0
};
const emptyValues = new Set(["", null, undefined]);
userData.counter = Object.values(userData).filter(x => emptyValues.has(x)).length;
console.log(userData);
```

We can use `reduce` instead of `filter` to minimize memory usage.

```js
const userData = {
  firstName: "Eric",
  lastName: null,
  age: "",
  location : "San francisco",
  country: "USA",
  counter: 0
};
const emptyValues = new Set(["", null, undefined]);
userData.counter = Object.values(userData).reduce((acc,curr) => acc + emptyValues.has(curr), 0);
console.log(userData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Objec.values` for accessing the values of the object and the function `Array.prototype.reduce` for counting the empty values.

```js
const userData = {  firstName: "Eric",  lastName: null,  age: "",  location : "San francisco",  country: "USA",  counter: 0},
      emptyValues = ["", null];
      
userData.counter = Object.values(userData).reduce((r, c) => r + emptyValues.includes(c), 0);
console.log(userData);
```